# How to Find which Program is generating given .dat File

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file in a folder on the server with ".dat" extension. I want to find which program file is generating this file.

How should I find this using putty?

Comment: Hi Toohina and welcome to Serverfault! PuTTY is an SSH client software, and this question has no information on the target system. Which distribution it is? What's the full path for the file created? Please edit your question and add more details on your issue.

Comment: The most efficient way would be using the audit subsystem with `auditctl`, but from this alone it is impossible to say whether the audit subsystem would be available on the target system & whether you have the root access required to enable auditing of a file.

Comment: I think Autosys runs a script or program and the .dat file is generated. Now, I want to find out which scrip/program it is running to generate this file. @EsaJokinen

Comment: Then, use the audit subsystem.